# Creating variable myhospitalstaff

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-insert

```
DECLARE @Myhospitalstaff TABLE(EmpID INT  NOT NULL, Name VARCHAR(50)  , Job VARCHAR(50) , HireDate Datetime , City  VARCHAR(50), State VARCHAR(50) )
SET   @Myhospitalstaff = (SELECT 
                        EMPID,
                       SUBSTRING(NameJob,1,CHARINDEX('_',NameJob)-1) AS Name,
                       SUBSTRING(NameJob,CHARINDEX('_',NameJob),LEN(NameJob)) AS Job,
                       HireDate,
                       SUBSTRING(Location,1,CHARINDEX('-',Location)-1) AS City,
                       SUBSTRING(Location, CHARINDEX('-',Location),LEN(Location)) AS State
FROM                   HospitalStaff)
```

Comment: Your question lacks a question.  As well as any guidance on what your data looks like and what you are doing.

Comment: Don't use [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26205514) to give feedback on answers. Type the feedback into the comment box under the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* you are looking to assign the results of the query to the table variable, then you need the `insert` syntax rather than `set` - and there is no need to alias the columns of the resultset (the table has its own column names already):

```
DECLARE @Myhospitalstaff TABLE(
    EmpID INT  NOT NULL, 
    Name VARCHAR(50), 
    Job VARCHAR(50), 
    HireDate Datetime, 
    City  VARCHAR(50), 
    State VARCHAR(50) 
);

INSERT INTO @Myhospitalstaff
SELECT 
    EMPID,
    SUBSTRING(NameJob,1,CHARINDEX('_',NameJob)-1),
    SUBSTRING(NameJob,CHARINDEX('_',NameJob),LEN(NameJob)),
    HireDate,
    SUBSTRING(Location,1,CHARINDEX('-',Location)-1),
    SUBSTRING(Location, CHARINDEX('-',Location),LEN(Location))
FROM HospitalStaff;
```

Comment: aliasing makes it more readable as no need to count the columns to see what the 6th item in the SELECT is supposed to be representing